# SSH crashes tmux session

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

I'm trying to achieve the following:

On host A, create a tmux session and start neovim in it.
On host B, connect to host A via ssh and attach to the session.

When I try to start neovim inside tmux on host A (locally), everything works as expected.
When I try to then connect via ssh, I get `[lost server]` on the ssh session and the terminal is unusable.
When I first ssh into the machine, then start a tmux session and then neovim inside of it, the same thing happens.

host A is a ubuntu 18.04 machine (tmux 2.6), host B arch linux.

Already tried (no luck):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892092/weird-tmux-vim-through-ssh
- `tmux -f /dev/null`, `nvim -u NONE`

`tmux -vvv` does not list errors in any of the files.

Comment: Does the tmux server die on A? I mean are you unable to `tmux a` locally on A after you see `[lost server]` on B? I guess so, but please confirm.

Comment: Yes, it dies: `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default`

Comment: The issue does not appear when I do `TERM=xterm-256-color tmux a`, so something in my TERM seems to be wrong.